# One-way Fixed model

Tags: anova, linear-model, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model

Duppose we have 12 treatments, and to start the experiment we choose these treatments, randomly. However, after selecting one treatment, all the samples are gathered and we shift to the next treatment and so on. It is obvious that samples are not INDEPENDENT. How can I analyse the data?

Answer (score 1):

If it can be avoided, such way of performing experiments is far the best possible, but its analysis is not very different.

By doing treatments one by one, you may be mixing the effect of every treatment with uncontrollable factors. For example, the time of day might influence the outcome of the experiment, and therefore the effects you are measuring from the first treatment include both effects from treatment and effects from the time you run the experiment for first treatment, and you won't be able to tell apart  that two causes. Therefore, it's better the usual approach of completely randomized experiments, where we can expect those unwanted effects to balance each other for the different replicas of each treatment - at least, to balance in a sizeable extent.

Anyway, the analysis is the same. The difference is just that instead of labelling the fist treatment outcome as "treatment 1", you will label it as "treatment 1 plus all effects arising by running those samples in the first place", and hope that most of the measured outcome will actually come from treatment.